# Was the "Gauss word realization problem" a kind of unknotting problem?

Tags: gauss, topology, graph-theory

In Moritz Epple's article "Geometric Aspects in the Development of Knot Theory", Epple writes the following:

> It has been suggested that one of the earliest tools of combinatorial knot theory was forged by Carl Friedrich Gauss. Some posthumously published fragments of his Nachlass, originally written in the years 1825 and 1844, document that the Gottingen mathematician tried to classify closed plane curves with a finite number of transverse self-intersections, sometimes called "Tractfiguren" (tract figures) by Gauss. To do so, he invented a symbolical coding of such figures. He assigned a number or letter to each crossing and then wrote down the sequence of crossing symbols that resulted from following the curve in a given direction from a given point (see Figure 1). To some extent, this symbol-sequence captured the characteristic features of the tract figure in the sense of Geometria situs, as Gauss preferred to call the as yet unexplored science of topology.

This is the description of an unsigned [Gauss code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_notation). Epple continues and describes some of Gauss's remarks on properties of Gauss codes of tract figures:

> Gauss noticed that the sequences arising in this way had to satisfy certain conditions: Each of the symbols representing one of the $n$ crossings had to appear exactly twice, once in an even and once in an odd place of the sequence. As Gauss noticed in 1844, however, these conditions were sufficient only for $n\le 4$. He thus set out to write down a table of the admissible sequences for five crossings, but he did not find a method to solve the general problem of determining exactly which symbol sequences satisfying the above conditions actually represented crossing sequences of "Tractfiguren".

Here Epple described Gauss's parity condition. After that he says:

> What reasons did Gauss have for looking at this matter? Unfortunately, the fragments themselves do not give a clear answer. From the perspective of later knot theory, Gauss's attempt might look like a first step toward knot tables, but we will see that he had other reasons for studying "Tractfiguren".

(I must say that this is not the only source I read about Gauss's classification of tract figures, but I am still confused.)

My question is very basic - are the "tract figures" mentioned in these passages supposed to be knot projections? in other words, is it possible that a symbols sequence which satisfies the parity condition cannot be realized as a plane curve? because if the answer to my second question is yes, that means that "restricted" Gauss codes (that satisfy the parity condition) are not equivalent to planar curves, and therefore the problem of Gauss word realization is merely about curves and is relavent only to graph theory and not to knot theory.

However, if the answer to my second question is no, than the Gauss word realization problem must be about classifying which Gauss words correspond to projections of 3D knots and which correspond to a projection of the unknot (which means that despite the tract figure may look complicated, it actually can be transformed by a series of valid steps into a single non self-intersecting loop, which is a projection of the unknot). Such an assumption seems to be consistent with the fact Gauss refers many times to these tract figures as "knots", but I did not find anywhere on web the assertion that Gauss word realization problem is simply an unknotting problem.

(I appologize for asking too many questions about very minor points, I know this is annoying, but this is simply my lack of rigorous mathematical knowledge combined with my lack of time that leads me to ask many questions with more or less overlapping themes.)